# Difference between sshv1 and 1.5?

Tags: encryption, ssh

I've been searching for the answer to this but haven't had much luck.

**What is the difference between SSH version 1 and 1.5?** Is 1.5 a release of 1? As in 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5?

Are there any additional security features added to 1.5?

TIA any help much appreciated

Comment: Can you confirm, are you talking about the protocol, or a specific implementation? If the protocol, then you should be using version 2.x, not 1.x, as it has inherent vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks Graham I was talking about the protocol. I am trying to harden cisco routers and noticed a lot of these are running v1.5 was just curious as to the difference. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are essentially only two real versions of the SSH protocol, SSH-1 and SSH-2.

**[SSH-1](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch03_04.htm)** 
SSHv1 had several iterations.  Each iteration fixed certain security issues, but the protocol itself is vulnerable to several attacks.  It uses RSA to encrypt 32 bytes of session key.  It uses both the server's key and the host key; as in it RSA encrypts the session key twice.  I know this sounds weird, but this is what happens.  Then the session key is shared with the server.

This protocol has inherent known vulnerabilities.  SSHv1.5 is known to be vulnerable to injecting data into encrypted packets [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Notable_vulnerabilities).  This is due to poor integrity checking using CRC32.  SSHv1 is also prone to Man in the Middle (MitM) attacks.  Here is a [paper on the subject](http://www.giac.org/paper/gsec/2034/conducting-ssh-man-middle-attacks-sshmitm/103515).

**[SSH-2](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch03_05.htm)**
SSHv2 is a completely different protocol.  It uses an Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman exchange with proper integrity checks of the entire exchange.  The entire packet is encrypted, including any SSH header information.  Session keys are generated from hashing the session id, shared secret, and the hash of the exchange with an ASCII letter.  There is a different letter for each session key needed session key or initialization vector needed.

The vulnerabilities in SSHv2 have only been theoretical.  So far the protocol is known to be secure when implemented correctly.

**SSH-1.99**
This isn't actually a version of the protocol.  The first piece of data exchanged by the client and server is their protocol version in what's called a protocol string.  This is the only compatibility the two protocols share.  Examples of version strings

`SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_2.5.2p2`
`SSH-2-OpenSSH_2.9p1`

SSH-1.99 is only ever sent by a server and it's how the server tells the client that it supports both SSH-1 and SSH-2.

**You should always use SSH-2.**  SSH-1 is known to be insecure.  99% of servers out there support SSH-2, and no known vulnerabilities against it.